# Testing the convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln{(k)}}{k} (-1)^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\ln{(k)}}{k}$ diverges by the comparison test. However, I'm not sure how to use the alternating series test to show that this particular series converges or diverges. Wolfram Alpha tells me that it converges to $\gamma \ln{(2)} - \dfrac{\ln^2{(2)}}{2}$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. But I have no idea where that answer comes from, as I can't easily prove that this converges by the alternating series test. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The alternating series test never tells us what the limit of a convergent series is, only that it converges. What is the difficulty with applying the alternating series test? It has two hypotheses; is either one hard to verify? Is it tough to understand what its conclusion is?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the lack of clarity. I'm having difficulty proving it converges by the AST. I can prove that the limit goes to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ but I'm having a hard time proving that it's decreasing.

Comment: Work with $\sum_{k=3}^{\infty} (-1)^k \dfrac{ln k}{k}$. Let $b_k = \dfrac{lnk}{k}$.Differentiate w.r.t $k$ and use the fact that $1-ln k<0$ for all $k \geq 3$.So, {$b_k$} is decreasing. Apply AST for this series to conclude the series is convergent. So does the orginial one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see that $f(n)\equiv\log(n)/n$ is decreasing, you can differentiate:
$$f'(n)=\frac{1}{n^2}\left(n\cdot\frac{1}{n}-\log(n)\right)=\frac{1-\log(n)}{n^2},$$
which is negative whenever $\log(n)>1$, i.e. whenever $n>e$. Hence, the series $\sum_{n=3}^\infty(-1)^n\log(n)/n$ converges, and therefore so does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\log(n)/n$.